# Validate form before submitted (Check all fields are entered)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check that the fields in the form below have been filled before it can be inserted into a database e.g. display a pop up with the fields that have not been filled in. It is just a simple Registration form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="signup_ac.php">
<strong>Sign up</strong>
Username:<input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30">
Password:<input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="15">
Name:<input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30">
<select name="Month">
<option selected>Month</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="Febuary">Febuary</option
  </select> 
<select name=Year>
<option selected>Year</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

How do I do this using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: It will be easier if you fill the `Select` year using js like: `function getYears(){for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--){$('#Year').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));}}`

Comment: True, and please limit your code example to some necessary snippets - the whole form is not relevant and 100 options with only the year changing either. Actually none of your code is relevant for the question. Form validation is a very general problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, download the [jQuery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) plugin and add it to your page. Then give each input you want to make a required field a class of `required`. Then in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").validate();
});
```

The validate plugin is very feature rich, so you can have different types of message displayed, different validation checks etc should you require. There's more information on that in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method).

Finally, as with all javascript front-end validation, make sure you validate user input on the server side too, just in case a user has javascript turned off in their browser.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (using jQuery) would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var err = $this.attr('id') + ' is required.';
        var errElem = $('<span />').text(err).css({'color': 'red', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
        if ($this.val().length === 0) {
            $this.parent('td').append(errElem);
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to do server-side validation as well. There are some users who disable JavaScript (and then this wouldn't run).

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I will have a normal html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function validateMe() {

if (firstname is blank) {
alert("Enter first name");
form.first.focus();
return false;
}

if (lastname is blank) {
alert("Enter last name");
form.last.focus();
return false;
}

return true;
}

</script>
<body>

// Form here

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateMe()">

</body>
</html>
```

if first name is blank, form never submit the form...

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

require('inc/mysqli_connect.php');
$errors=array();

/*Verifica el nombre*/
if(empty($_POST['first_name'])){
    $errors[]='Verifique el campo de Nombre del participante';
}else{
    $fina=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['first_name']));
}

/*Verifica el apellido paterno*/
if(empty($_POST['ape_pat'])){
    $errors[]='Verifique el campo de Apellido Paterno del participante';
}else{
    $appa=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ape_pat']));
}

/*Verifica el apellido materno*/
if(empty($_POST['ape_mat'])){
    $errors[]='Verifique el campo de Apellido Materno del participante';
}else{
    $apma=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ape_mat']));
}

/*Verifica el genero*/
if(empty($_POST['gender'])){
    $errors[]='Seleccione el Género del participante';
}else{
    $gend=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['gender']));
}

/*Verifica el correo electronico*/
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors[]='Verifique el campo de Correo Electrónico del participante';
}else{
    $coel=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
}

/*and repeat the code above for all the input that you have in your form */

if(empty($errors)){
    $q="INSERT INTO participante(nombre, paterno, materno, genero, correo, fechadenac, procedencia, ocupacion, asistencia, fechareg) VALUES ('$fina','$appa','$apma','$gend','$coel','$dabi','$prov','$ocup','$assi',NOW())";
    $r=mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    if($r){
        echo '
            <p>
                Nombre: <b>'.$_POST['first_name'].'</b><br />
                Apellido Paterno: <b>'.$_POST['ape_pat'].'</b><br />
                Apellido Materno: <b>'.$_POST['ape_mat'].'</b><br />
                Genero: <b>'.$_POST['gender'].'</b><br />
                Correo Electrónico: <b>'.$_POST['email'].'</b><br />
                Fecha de nacimiento: <b>'.$_POST['date'].'</b><br />
                Procedencia: <b>'.$_POST['provenance'].'</b><br />
                Ocupación: <b>'.$_POST['ocuppation'].'</b><br />
                ¿Asistió? <b>'.$_POST['assistance'].'</b><br />
            </p>
            ';          
    }else{
        echo '
            <h2><a>¡Error del Sistema!</a></h2>
            <p>
                El registro no pudo realizarse debido a un error del sistema. Disculpe los incovenientes.<br />
            </p>
            <p>
                Error: '.mysqli_error($dbc).'<br />
                Query: '.$q.'<br />
            </p>
        ';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    include ('inc/footer.html');
    exit();
}else{
    echo '
        <p>
            Revise que todo los campos hayan sido llenados correctamente.<br /> 
            Se encontraron los siguientes errores: <br />                           
    ';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) {
        echo " - $msg<br />\n";
    }
    echo '
        </p>
        <p>
            Ingrese los datos faltantes e intente de nuevo.
        </p>
    ';
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

}